# DNS issue with debian

Tags: debian, dns

I have openmediavault for my files server, based on debian 11 (bullseye).

I formatted the computer after I had the same problem i'm facing now- dns problem.
the problem began this time after upgrading the system (apt-get upgrade) and the last time some days after intalling Plex application

By dns problem I mean that I have connectivity to the internet because I have ping to 8.8.8.8 but I don't have ping to dns.google:
[pings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eud8Y.png)

What I tried:

- I added to /etc/resolv.conf nameserver 8.8.8.8 and 1.1.1.1:
  [resolv.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvkGv.png)
- I added to /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf the line supersede domain-name-servers 1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8; as the pictue below and after run command dhclient -r; sudo dhclient
  [dhclient.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N11nP.png)
- Time is correct on IDT time.
- I have local dns, as shown in picture, I have ping to another computer on local network by dns name:
  [local DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZN88.png)
- I don't have dig command:
  [dig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HayCp.png)

Can anyone tell me what am I missing?

Comment: up. still waiting an answer

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, dumb one, but it fixed my problem!

I entered the omv WebUI, and under System -> interfaces I edited the interface and added the DNS I wanted (in my case 8.8.8.8 and my router).

I don't know why this helped...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Eitan, what exact field did you modify ?

Comment: Because I don't have the OMV right now (I replaced it with another server) so I can send here a link that tells how to change the IP address, but I changed the DNS (also can be seen in the video):
https://www.google.com/search?q=network+configurations+omv&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIL1077IL1077&oq=network+configurations+omv&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIICAEQABgWGB7SAQg3NzI2ajBqNKgCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:492aaa49,vid:x-1UWAvZws4,st:0